# Thread-Safe lazy instantiating using MEF

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, mef, lazy-evaluation

```
// Member Variable
private static readonly object _syncLock = new object();

// Now inside a static method

foreach (var lazyObject in plugins)
{
   if ((string)lazyObject.Metadata["key"] = "something")
   {
      lock (_syncLock)
      {
         // It seems the `IsValueCreated` is not up-to-date
         if (!lazyObject.IsValueCreated) 
            lazyObject.value.DoSomething();
      }
      return lazyObject.value;
   }
}
```

Here I need synchronized access per loop. There are many threads iterating this loop and based on the `key` they are looking for, a lazy instance is created and returned.

`lazyObject` should not be created more that one time. Although `Lazy` class is for doing so and despite of the used lock, under high threading I have more than one instance created (I track this with a `Interlocked.Increment` on a `volatile` `static int` and log it somewhere). The problem is I don't have access to definition of `Lazy` and `MEF` defines how the `Lazy` class create objects. I should notice the `CompositionContainer` has a thread-safe option in constructor which is already used.

My questions:

1) Why the lock doesn't work ?

2) Should I use an array of locks instead of one lock for performance improvement ?

Comment: Something isn't quite right in that code (which makes it hard to see the problem you have). You've got a non-static member variable of a class being accessed by a static member function (which won't compile)

Comment: That's static of course. edited.

Comment: Try to move `return lazyObject.value` to inside the lock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the default constructor of `T` in your `Lazy` complex? MEF uses `LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly` which means each thread accessing the unitialised `Lazy` will generate a `new()` on `T` until the first to complete the initialisation.  That value is then returned for all threads currently accessing `.Value` and their own `new()` instances are discarded.  If your constructor is complex (perhaps doing too much?) you should redefine it as doing minimal construction work and moving configuration to another method.

You need to think about the method as a whole.  Should you consider:

```
public IPlugin GetPlugin(string key)
{
  mutex.WaitOne();

  try
  {
    var plugin = plugins
      .Where(l => l.Metadata["key"] == key)
      .Select(l => l.Value);
      .FirstOrDefault();

    return plugin;
  }
  finally
  {
    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
  }
}
```

You also need to consider that if `plugins` is not read-only then you need to synchronise access to that instance too, otherwise it may be modified on another thread, causing your code to fall over.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't `lock` do the same as `mutex` here ? Why with synchronized access to `IsValueCreated` a thread could even try to create another instance ?

Comment: The `IsValueCreated` property simply checks that an internal object is initialised.  This internal property (only if `LazyThreadSafetyModel.ExecutionAndPublication`) is guaranteed to be write-synchronised for initialisers. Through `PublicationOnly`, this is not guaranteed.

Comment: That didn't work. I moved the `increment` into `DoSomthing()` method and still it's increasing. It means it's not just about constructor, it's about `IsValueCreated`

Comment: Can you update your question with your updated method AND declaration of any static values/mutexs

Comment: It's a lot of code but the concept is same. Since `lock` doesn't block new threads, it means even after the previous thread has released the `lock` the `IsValueCreated` is still `false`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific constructor of `Lazy<T, TMetadata>` for such scenarios, where you define a `LazyThreadSafetyMode` when constructing a Lazy instance... Otherwise, the lock might not work for many different reasons, e.g. if this is not the only place where the `Value` property of this `Lazy<T>` instance is ever accessed.

Btw you got I typo in the `if` statement...

Comment: This is the only place `value` is accessed. About `Lazy` constructor, read question again.

Comment: It is hard to say from what you have posted, but if MEF is creating the Lazy instance in 'PublicationOnly' mode as Matthew is writing above, then it is possible that several instances of 'T' are created but there should be only one instance assigned to the 'Value' property. The other instances are discarded, as the documentation states. So in my opinion (and under the assumption that 'plugins' is a read-only collection) there is no need to lock anything...