# Using per item locks inside a loop

Tags: c#, performance, loops, thread-safety

I have a `static` method which is accessed by many threads at the same time. For thread-safety `collection` this method iterating over would not change is size (no add/no delete). Note that item is a `Lazy` object and I don't have access to `Lazy` constructor to use the thread-safe one (`MEF` do that):

```
private static readonly object _syncLock = new object();

// Now inside a static method

private static DoSomethingOnItem(string wanted)
{
   foreach (var item in items)
   {
      if (item.Metadata["Name"] = wanted)
      {
         lock (_syncLock)
            item.DoSomething();
      }
   }
}
```

Does it boost performance if I use and array of `locks` per item or many `locks` have much side-effect rather than performance boosting ?

```
private static object[] _syncLocks;
// Code...
_syncLocks = new object[itemsCount]; // in a thread-safe manner
```

Then inside the loop use each `item` specific `lock`

Comment: Use a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` instead. No need to reinvent the wheel. :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx

Comment: possible repeat of [Thread-Safe lazy instantiating using MEF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633634/thread-safe-lazy-instantiating-using-mef)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just lock on the item object, rather than create an array of locks?

I.e.

```
private static void DoSomethingOnItem(string wanted)
{
   foreach (var item in items)
   {
      if (item.name == wanted)
      {
         lock (item)
            item.DoSomething();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Item is `Lazy` here so there's no instance before `DoSomething()` call.

Comment: @Xaqron: if the item doesn't exist, how are you testing its name?